# Showing status while javascript in process

Tags: javascript

I've been using a location script that displays `$( "div.logintomessage" ).fadeIn( 320 ).delay( 1400 ).fadeOut( 320 );` with a message written in the div. However, I would like to show the `div` with the progress of the operation. i.e.: "locating you", "error if applicable", "Located you".

I have the script showing this functionality using `result = document.getElementById("located");`  and `result.innerHTML = "Getting your location...";` but I can't style the `div` or only show it while js is in process. I'm not even sureif I need to use `innerHTML`, I found it on the web.

Comment: Please include the complete script you are attempting to modify, ideally in the form of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your two examples are 1) jQuery, and 2) vanilla JavaScript. Which one are you using?

Comment: Keep in mind I'm very new to this :)

Comment: here is the pen, https://codepen.io/NickGalgay/pen/XWgJqbZ

Comment: You might have to call the `fadeIn`, `delay` and `fadeOut` at different parts of your application. Also if you look at the [fadeIn documentation](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) you can see that the second parameter is `complete` which is a function which is called when the animation is done. You can find example code there.